# How to remove packery by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, packery

I am trying to use packery jquery pluging in my project. everything is working fine but i need to delete packery only when i click minimise button on right corner . how can i do this please help me friends.

here is my code

```
<div class="packery" >
<div class="module-sizer"></div>
  <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
  <div class="module">
    <remove headertitle="Mine"></remove>
  </div>
  <div class="module" >
    <remove headertitle="team lead"></remove>
  </div>
</div>
```

js code

```
app.directive('packery', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    constrain: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.ready(function() {
        var packery = new Packery(element[0], {
          rowHeight: '.module-sizer',
          itemSelector: '.module',
          columnWidth: '.module-sizer'
        });

        //this part is for remove 
        //this should be done only on button click
        var packerys = $('.packery').packery();

        packerys.on( 'click', function( event ) {
          packerys.packery( 'remove', event.target );
          packerys.packery();
        }); 

        angular.forEach(packery.getItemElements(), function(item) {
          var draggable = new Draggabilly(item);

          packery.bindDraggabillyEvents(draggable);
        });
        packery.layout();
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

thanks

Comment: please provide your code, you use jquery or vanilla js ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i am using  jquery

Comment: please provide your code. what you have tried

Comment: here is it u can see  code now

Comment: if you don't know how implement destroy method into angular directive, then your question should be angular question not jquery

Answer (score 0):

you probably want [destroy](http://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html#destroy) method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i need to remove particular packery by clicking